# What's the best way to run method of Component (Service) just after bootstrap running?

Tags: nestjs

I'm using NestJS instance as microservice (without HTTP).

I need to run Component's method that is infinity loop with some business logic just after bootstrap initialization.

What is the best way to do it?

**src/main.ts**

```
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {ApplicationModule} from './app.module';
import {Transport} from '@nestjs/microservices';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
    app.connectMicroservice({
        transport: Transport.REDIS,
        url: 'redis://:redis_pass@localhost:6379',
    });
    await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();

    // Probably here I must run startLoop method from app.service.ts
    
}
bootstrap();
```

**src/app.service.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@nestjs/common';

@Component()
export class AppService {

    startLoop() {
        let timerId = setTimeout(function loop() {
            console.log('Loop process');
            // Some business logic here
            timerId = setTimeout(loop, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that you should implement `OnModuleInit` interface. [Read more about lifecycle hooks](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#usage).